# WinSCP .NET assembly - Session output gets too big

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net

I am using the WinSCP .NET assembly in order to "monitor" on a FTP server, and download every file that is uploaded to the FTP server.

After leaving my program running all night, the ram usage was over 1gb, and after debugging and checking with profiling programs, it happened because of `Session.Output`, which is an Enumerable collection of strings, which never gets cleared, and collects everything that happens to this Enumerable instead into a log file. I tried adding log file paths to `Session.DebugLogPath` and `Session.SessionLogPath`, which copied the Enumerable into a file, but didn't clear it.

How can I disable / clear the `Session.Output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [WinSCP 5.7.6](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/history?a=5.7.6), WinSCP .NET assembly [holds only the last 1000 lines of the output](https://winscp.net/tracker/1367).

Please upgrade.

---

Note that the [`Session.Output`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#output) is not related to the `Session.SessionLogPath` or the `Session.DebugLogPath`. They each log different information.

Comment: Ok, thank you! For now I will dispose and reset the session when it reaches 300,000 files, and wait for Version 5.7.6 :)

Comment: I saw version 5.7.6 is out, but this bug isn't fixed there. Did you postpone it to the next version?

Comment: @user5441417 No I didn't postpone it. The fix is there. The `Session.Output` never grows over 1000 lines.

Comment: I see, the Bug 1367 was not in [the WinSCP 5.7.6 version history](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/history?a=5.7.6). I've added it.

Comment: Which can I use better `SessionLogPath` or `DebugLogPath` ?

Comment: @PreguntonCojoneroCabrón This is not a discussion forum. If you have a question, please post a separate question. Though you need to explain your use case.

Comment: do you know the answer and cannot publish here? Post question maybe.